# Bank conflict CUDA shared memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

I'm running into (what I believe are) shared-memory bank conflicts in a CUDA kernel. The code itself is fairly complex, but I reproduced it in the simple example attached below.

In this case it is simplified to a simple copy from global -> shared -> global memory, of a 2D array of size 16x16, using a shared-memory array which might be padded at the right side (variable `ng`).

If I compile the code with `ng=0` and examine the *shared memory access pattern* with NVVP, it tells me that there are *"no issues"*. With e.g. `ng=2` I get *"Shared Store Transactions/Access = 2, Ideal Transactions/Acces = 1"* at the lines marked with *"NVVP warning"*. I don't understand why (or more specific: why the padding causes the warnings).

**EDIT** *as mentioned by Greg Smith below, on Kepler there are 32 banks of 8 bytes wide (http://gpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/08-opti-smem-instr.pdf, slide 18). But I don't see how that changes the problem.*

If I understand things correctly, with 32 banks `(B1, B2, ..)` of 4 bytes, doubles `(D01, D02, ..)` are stored as:

```
B1   B2   B3   B4   B5    ..   B31
----------------------------------
D01       D02       D03   ..   D15
D16       D17       D18   ..   D31
D32       D33       D34   ..   D47
```

Without the padding, half warps write (`as[ijs] = in[ij]`) to shared-memory `D01 .. D15`, `D16 .. D31`, etc. With padding (of size 2) the first half warp writes to `D01 .. D15`, the second after the padding to `D18 .. D33`, which still shouldn't cause a bank conflict?

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Simplified example (tested with cuda 6.5.14):

```
// Compiled with nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_35 -lineinfo 

__global__ void copy(double * const __restrict__ out, const double * const __restrict__ in, const int ni, const int nj, const int ng)

{
    extern __shared__ double as[];
    const int ij=threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*blockDim.x;
    const int ijs=threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*(blockDim.x+ng);

    as[ijs] = in[ij]; // NVVP warning
    __syncthreads();
    out[ij] = as[ijs]; // NVVP warning
}

int main()
{
    const int itot = 16;
    const int jtot = 16;
    const int ng = 2;
    const int ncells = itot * jtot;

    double *in  = new double[ncells];
    double *out = new double[ncells];
    double *tmp = new double[ncells];
    for(int n=0; n<ncells; ++n)
        in[n]  = 0.001 * (std::rand() % 1000) - 0.5;

    double *ind, *outd;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&ind,  ncells*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&outd, ncells*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(ind,  in,  ncells*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(outd, out, ncells*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 gridGPU (1, 1 , 1);
    dim3 blockGPU(16, 16, 1);

    copy<<<gridGPU, blockGPU, (itot+ng)*jtot*sizeof(double)>>>(outd, ind, itot, jtot, ng);

    cudaMemcpy(tmp, outd, ncells*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bank layout for gk110 is dependent on the bank width which is configurable to 4bytes or 8bytes.

Comment: Would that mean that in 8 byte mode doubles `D01..D31` are stored in different banks, and `D01` and `D32` share a bank? I can't seem to find any detailed info on that.

Comment: Seems to be the case; http://gpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/08-opti-smem-instr.pdf. I added that to my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I didn’t understand the Keppler architecture correctly. As pointed out in one of the comments above by Greg Smith, Keppler can be configured to have 32 shared memory banks of 8 bytes. In such a case, using `cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig( cudaSharedMemBankSizeEightByte )`, the shared memory layout looks like:

```
bank:  B0   B1   B2   B3   B4    ..   B31
       ----------------------------------
index: D00  D01  D02  D03  D04   ..   D31
       D32  D33  D34  D35  D36   ..   D63
```

Now, for my simple example (using `itot=16`), the writing/reading to/from shared memory on e.g. the first two rows (`threadIdx.y=0`, `threadIdx.y=1`) is handled within one warp. This means that for `threadIdx.y=0` values `D00..D15` are stored in `B0..B15`, then there is a padding of two doubles, after which within the same warp values `D18..D33` are stored in `B18..B31+B00..B01`, which causes a bank conflict on `B00-B01`. Without the padding (`ng=0`) the first row is written to `D00..D15` in `B00..B15`, the second row in `D16..D31` in `B16..B31`, so no bank conflict occurs.

For a thread block of `blockDim.x>=32` the problem shouldn’t occur. For example, for `itot=32`, `blockDim.x=32`, `ng=2`, the first row is stored in banks `B00..B31`, then two cells padding, second row in `B02..B31+B00..B01`, etc.